# mysql select count for multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, select, count, nullif

I have a table that contains elements.

Each element has its parent `instance_id`, a `number_of_lines` of code,
and a `deletion_date` when removed.

I built a query that counts the elements grouped by instance with totals for elements that have code ( `number_of_lines` not zero) and elements that have been removed (`deletion_date` not null)

```
SELECT instance_id, 
    COUNT(id) AS elementsfound,
    COUNT(NULLIF(number_of_lines,0)) AS havecode,
    (COUNT(id)-COUNT(NULLIF(number_of_lines,0))) AS havenocode,      
    COUNT(deletion_date) AS beenremoved,          
    (COUNT(id)-COUNT(deletion_date)) AS stillexistent        
  FROM elements        
  GROUP BY instance_id
```

and I obtain a correct result of (abbreviated)

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| instance_id | elementsfound | havecode | havenocode | beenremoved | stillexistent |
+-------------+---------------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
|          59 |         93123 |    24109 |      69014 |       45397 |         47726 |
|          69 |         46399 |     7837 |      38562 |       23929 |         22470 |
|          71 |         41752 |     8746 |      33006 |        6960 |         34792 |
|          75 |         29097 |     4303 |      24794 |       13670 |         15427 |
|          77 |         41681 |     9858 |      31823 |       10540 |         31141 |
|          79 |         17800 |      695 |      17105 |       13391 |          4409 |
|          82 |         25323 |     2481 |      22842 |       20914 |          4409 |
|          83 |         12831 |     2544 |      10287 |        2988 |          9843 |
```

...

Now, I want to add a column with the number of elements per instance that **both** are still existent (`deletion_date` is null) **and** have code (`number_of_lines` are different than zero)

I have found no way to either add a `NULLIF` nor a `CASE WHEN` with multiple columns.

How can I include a multiple-column-conditional counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that still existent records should have deletion_date NULL.

Try this:

```
SELECT instance_id, 
    COUNT(id) AS elementsfound,
    COUNT(NULLIF(number_of_lines,0)) AS havecode,
    (COUNT(id)-COUNT(NULLIF(number_of_lines,0))) AS havenocode,      
    COUNT(deletion_date) AS beenremoved,          
    (COUNT(id)-COUNT(deletion_date)) AS stillexistent,
    COUNT(IF(deletion_date IS NULL AND number_of_lines > 0, 1, NULL)) existentwithcode
  FROM elements        
  GROUP BY instance_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do?

```
sum( if(deletion_date is null and number_of_lines!=0, 1, 0) )
```

Comment: yes, +1 that approaches it too, eventhoug its the reverse of what I was wanting to do (@Pan has also fixed my intention as well)